# magento with apc under win7x64

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp, apc

i want to speed up magento with apc under windows
i'm using xampp 3.1.0 and downloaded a precompiled apc from
http://www.dragffy.com/php-extensions (PHP Alternative PHP Cache APC 3.1.13 built against PHP 5.4.7 x86 VC9) and added it to php.ini

I'm running win7 x64.

When i open the included apc.php it shows some apc statistics.

But when i open my magento, apache crashes with

```
  Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   httpd.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    2.4.3.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    502f70a3
  Fehlermodulname:  php5ts.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   5.4.7.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   505114f8
  Ausnahmecode: c0000005
  Ausnahmeoffset:   000356c1
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Zusatzinformation 3:  0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0407

Wenn die Onlinedatenschutzbestimmungen nicht verfügbar sind, lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\de-DE\erofflps.txt
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [Magento's official system requirements page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements):

> Supported Operating Systems: Linux x86, x86-64

I know this doesn't solve the problem, and to be honest I couldn't care less if I get negative reputation for this, but you are better off (trust me!) switching to a *nix based operating system.

Comment: i know, but development in win is more comfortable, our unix server runs fine with apc

Comment: You should try and go for a virtualbox development environment that runs on your Windows OS.